# PDO while loop to reuse output template

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, while-loop

I'm trying to use PDO in this way and reuse the output template:

```
 selected_products_show .= '<div class="'.$product_id.'">'.$product_name.'</div>';
```

To be used for the two queries which will be executed since both $ordered=1 & $shipped=1.
The issue is in the output section:

```
<?php if ($ordered == 1) { echo $selected_products_show;}?>
<?php if ($shipped == 1) { echo $selected_products_show;}?>
```

$selected_product_show gets overwritten by the second loop where $shipped=1. How can I pull out the correct query(which happens now) and attach the correct loop with the correct variable display for that loop (All with one while loop, while reusing the same output template)?

Here is the code:

```
$ordered = 1;
$shipped = 1;

if ($ordered == 1) {
$queryEnd = "WHERE product_id IN (?,?,?)";
}
if ($shipped == 1) {
$queryEnd = "ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 5";
}

$query = "SELECT product_id, product_name FROM products $queryEnd";

if ($ordered == 1) {
$ordered_products = array(1,2,3);
$selected_products = $dbh->prepare($query);
$selected_products->execute($ordered_products);
}
if ($shipped == 1) {
$selected_products = $dbh->prepare($query);
$selected_products->execute();
}

while($row = $selected_products->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $product_id = $row["product_id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $selected_products_show .= '<div class="'.$product_id.'">'.$product_name.'</div>';
}

<?php if ($ordered == 1) { echo $selected_products_show;}?>
<?php if ($shipped == 1) { echo $selected_products_show;}?>
```

Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Really? Why is that? You might have to reuse the same exact output from the while loop but with different correct PDO statements. Imagine you had to output a 1,000 lines of output, you'd have 3,000 lines of the same exact thing repeated, instead of 1,000. I actually think it's more efficient in situations like this.

Comment: @YourCommonSense So how would you go about doing it right then?

Comment: I'd separate my business logic (which about getting and preparing data) from display logic (which about displaying data). So, PDO will remain in the business logic part while passing only data into template. And of course I'd implement pagination, to display only 100 lines per page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function templating($selected_products){
  $selected_products_show = '';
  while($row = $selected_products->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $product_id = $row["product_id"];
        $product_name = $row["product_name"];
        $selected_products_show .= '<div class="'.$product_id.'">'.$product_name.'</div>';
  }
 return $selected_products_show;
}

$ordered = 1;
$shipped = 1;
$queryMAIN = "SELECT product_id, product_name FROM products";

if ($ordered == 1) {
    $query = $queryMAIN." WHERE product_id IN (?,?,?)";
    $ordered_products = array(1,2,3);
    $selected_products = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $selected_products->execute($ordered_products);
    echo templating($selected_products);
}

if ($shipped == 1) {
    $query= $queryMAIN." ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 5";
    $selected_products = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $selected_products->execute();
    echo templating($selected_products);
}
```

Something like this?

Comment: Works perfectly with the new edit! Thanks egis for your help!